# How to call controller class from jsp in spring

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I want to store the users every detail like users-agent and some more headers and the name of url page which user hit recently for that i have made one controller class for storing all detail  and i have more than 20 pages  how can call HelloController class from the back end when user hit on my jsp pages so that i store the all headers ,time and  url in the database

```
    @Controller
    public class HelloController {

        @RequestMapping(value = "/StroreHits")
        public String hello(
                @RequestHeader(value="Accept") String accept,
                @RequestHeader(value="Accept-Language") String acceptLanguage,
                @RequestHeader(value="User-Agent", defaultValue="foo") String userAgent,
                HttpServletResponse response) {

            System.out.println("accept: " + accept);
            System.out.println("acceptLanguage: " + acceptLanguage);
            System.out.println("userAgent: " + userAgent);
          String url_name   = request.getRequestURL().toString() + "?" + request.getQueryString()

         StoreHits sh =  new StoreHits ();
sh.insertValues(accept,acceptLanguage,userAgent,name);
            return null;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Well, in your JSP page, you need to create an html form/button or any other UI control that sends a request to your Controller class. If that's what you are trying to do and its not working then please post the code for the jsp page as well.

Comment: suppose you are hitting on some url like exaple.com/index at that time i want to store you every detail in database one way is i write the same code to all controller class getting and storing all  headers of user but i want to write that code only once and inclued response of that controler to the page

Comment: I used filter for that work in jsp ..  should i use filters in spring too ? or is there any other way ?

Comment: Using servlet filter is not a good idea here because you will not have access to spring container applicationcontext, Using Interceptors is a better idea, please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> suppose you are hitting on some url like exaple.com/index at that time i want to store you every detail in database one way is i write the same code to all controller class getting and storing all headers of user

You need to write Spring MVC interceptor which gets called before each and every request you send to your spring Controllers.

You can check [Spring MVC Interceptors Example](http://www.journaldev.com/2676/spring-mvc-interceptors-example-handlerinterceptor-and-handlerinterceptoradapter)

Comment: Thank You Tarun Gupta for the help its been 1 week i started spring i didn't know about Spring MVC Interceptors  :-)